# Python parou de funcionar visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Criei 2 classes, sendo que uma importa de outra e dava erro no import. Pesquisei na internet e falaram para ir na paleta de comando e escolher o interpretador (no meu sistema só tem um: Python 3.6 (64bit) - Windows. Cliquei lá, reiniciei o VScode e sumiu os avisos de erro do import. Mas agora não funciona nenhum arquivo python. Joguei a resposta na internet, inclusive em inglês, mas não consegui achar uma solução.

Caminho python no settings do vscode: python.pythonPath": "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe"

xxxxx = meu nome de usuário do windows.

**OBS: no prompt de comando funciona perfeitamente os scripts de python.**

Segue a imagem com o erro, e também o erro em texto logo depois:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> PS C:\python> teste.py
>   teste.py : O termo 'teste.py' não é reconhecido como nome de cmdlet, função, arquivo de script ou programa operável. Verifique a grafia do nome ou, se um
>   caminho tiver sido incluído, veja se o caminho está correto e tente novamente.
>   No linha:1 caractere:1
>   + teste.py
>   + ~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (teste.py:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> Suggestion [3,General]: O comando teste.py não foi encontrado, mas
>   existe no local atual. Por padrão, o Windows PowerShell não carrega
>   comandos do local atual. Se você confia nesse comando, digite:
>   ".\teste.py". Consulte "get-help about_Command_Precedence" para obter
>   mais detalhes. PS C:\python>

Comment: Já tentou `python teste.py`?

Comment: Sim, depois de ler seu comentário tentei com python na frente e também não funciona. Instalei o atom e está acontecendo o mesmo problema. Também removi o python das variáveis de ambiente e inseri novamente, tanto o o diretório como o executável e não adiantou. Testei no prompt do windows mais uma vez e nele continua funcionando.

Comment: E tentou o `.\teste.py` como sugere a mensagem de erro?

Comment: (Sim, .\teste.py eu tentei antes de reinstalar.) Reinstalei o python, agora está funcionando, desse jeito que você falou, digitando python na frente...mas será que tem como voltar ao que era antes? só o nome do arquivo.py?

Comment: Você está usando PowerShell correto? Veja isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813435/im-trying-to-use-python-in-powershell. Uso python no VsCode mas com o cmd no terminal.

Comment: Uso o powershell pelo visualcode, porque ele usa. (eu mesmo nemsei entrar nele por outro lugar, sei que tem um comando no cmd ou algo assim, mas nunca usei, só vi alguém usar). De qualquer forma tentei fazer o que disseram lá mas também não adiantou...mas pra falar a verdade não entendi bem o que o cara quis dizer com isso:  $env:path="$env:Path;C:\Python27"....abri as variáveis de ambiente e tentei inserir isso e não deu certo, tentei pelo cmd ou pelo powershell também não deu....

Answer (score 1):

Não esta identificando o caminho correto do seu interpretador PY, para corrigir:

Aperte as teclas de atalho: CTRL+SHIFT+P
Procure por "Python: Select Interpreter"

[image: Encontre a configuação "Python: Select Interpreter"]

Selecione o interpretador recomendado ou correto. (Recomendo selecionar o próprio Py).

[image: "Selecione o interpretador"]

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).